# XML file styling with XSLT but different row or filter by tree name

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

Hello XML gurus and pros. I have a question how to style an xml tree if the tree is like that:

```
 1. ROW

Name
Surname
Type

 2. ROW

Name
Surname
Type

 3. ROW

ID
Name
Surname
```

I need to write xslt code that it show ROW 1(famous) and ROW 2(famous), but did not show ROW 3, and filter all ROW that did not have ID field in the tree, so answer must be that code will show Row1 and Row2. So how to do that ?
Code example here:
Some example, i can't provide original xml file, because it's secure information. Thanks for reply try to give you example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<testdocument>
<famous>
<name>Bob</name>
<surname>Bobby</surname>
<type>Human</type>
</famous>
<famous>
<name>Ted</name>
<surname>Teddy</surname>
<type>Human</type>
</famous>
<famous>
<name>Snake</name>
<surname>Anaconda</surname>
<type>Reptile</type>
<ID>ANIMAL</ID>
</famous>
</testdocument>
```

And i need to output famous leaf first and second but not ouput third leaf where ID is set to something. So i need output all but not famous leaf where is ID set to something, hope that i asked correctly. The possible ouput:

```
Bob
Bobby
Human

Ted
Teddy
Human
```

And that's it.

This is the XSLT I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Here i think something must be written as condition that 
     ID field not be taken, and ROw3 name and surname not be shown too..-->
<xsl:for-each select="famous[ID != 0]"> 
<xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
<xsl:value-of select="SURNAME"/>
<xsl:value-of select="TYPE"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of the XML file rather than a description of it? And what is your desired output?  Do you want to show only rows that have IDs? Or show only rows that *do not* have IDs? Or something else?

Comment: I have edited my topic, can you recheck what i'm asking ? Thank you JLRishe

Comment: Ok, edited my answer.  Please give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="testdocument/famous[not(ID)]" />
        <pre>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="print" />
        </pre>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="famous">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    <br />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="famous/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="spaces">
    <xsl:text>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="print">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="spaces" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', local-name(), '&gt;')"/>
    <xsl:if test="*">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="print" />

    <xsl:if test="*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="spaces" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', local-name(), '&gt;')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]" mode="print" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result when run on your sample data:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>Bob<br>Bobby<br>Human<br><br>Ted<br>Teddy<br>Human<br><br><pre>&lt;testdocument&gt;
   &lt;famous&gt;
      &lt;name&gt;Bob&lt;/name&gt;
      &lt;surname&gt;Bobby&lt;/surname&gt;
      &lt;type&gt;Human&lt;/type&gt;
   &lt;/famous&gt;
   &lt;famous&gt;
      &lt;name&gt;Ted&lt;/name&gt;
      &lt;surname&gt;Teddy&lt;/surname&gt;
      &lt;type&gt;Human&lt;/type&gt;
   &lt;/famous&gt;
   &lt;famous&gt;
      &lt;name&gt;Snake&lt;/name&gt;
      &lt;surname&gt;Anaconda&lt;/surname&gt;
      &lt;type&gt;Reptile&lt;/type&gt;
      &lt;ID&gt;ANIMAL&lt;/ID&gt;
   &lt;/famous&gt;
&lt;/testdocument&gt;
</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, but how to do if that unique field is exist in leaf member ? for example if ID is in famouse leaf just output that row with ID field ? [is(ID)] ?

Comment: In that case it would be just `[ID]`.

Comment: And last question, how to check if in that field is something written what to do ? if it is empty what to do ?

Comment: To check whether it has an ID with a non-blank value: `[ID != '']`; to check whether it has a blank value: `[ID = '']`. To check whether it has no ID _or_ an ID with a blank value: `[not(ID) or ID  = '']`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think i want again one answer to my question after sweet html style answer to the browser, i need the same xml show in the same window as xml file tree, as raw xml. 
Ted 
Teddy 
Human

    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    //all xml stuff

How to do that ?

Comment: So you want an XSLT that will reproduce the source XML, but with the items with IDs removed?

Comment: Yes i want to xslt reproduce xml file all in web browser after the html, reproduce a original it looks like, with tree and all nodes. but all elements not affecting with style.

Comment: Well when you create xml, and check it in browser, you see all xml tree with nodes yes ? without any of touch of xslt, just raw xml is show in browser in tree mode. That view i need to print to browser after the xslt is done. with xslt i get data what i have asked you and after that data i need to show again the original xml printed with all nodes.

Comment: Yes, when it's shown in the browser it looks like XML underneath the ordinary text.  Why not try it out for yourself?  Do you want to display ALL of the original XML, or omit `<famous>` nodes with IDs?

Comment: I would do that if i would know how, because when i apply xslt, you see nice design. I need all XML printed below the design. Don't know how, new to XML learning things and i ran to this problem.

Comment: What I'm saying is, why not apply the XSLT I provided above and see what the result is?

Comment: Oh i got the results, thanks for that, but in the same window i need to print ALL XML too, all tree without styling. All XML below the styling in the same browser window.

Comment: Alright, I think what you mean is that you want the whole XML without filtering out anything.  Is that right?  If so, please try the XSLT I just updated above.

Comment: Is there any way to display orginally like webbrowser displays when open xml without aggregating code as you have done ? in <iframe></iframe> tage ? Your code is working fine with example i given, but it doesn't display information in my code in which actualy i work, but the results i got. Left only to display xml your aggregation doesn't work for me. So i need to display in iframe tag.

Comment: Yes, I suspect an `iframe` would work, if you set its `src` value to the location of the XML file, but I haven't tried it.  Perhaps you could open a separate question about that since I answered your original question?

Comment: JLRishe, you are the best, thanks for help ! the iframe worked :) and don't needed any aggregation. You are true expert of xml :) hope one day i have that knowledge too.